# Passing (large binary) data to appengine task

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a task endpoint that needs to process data (say >1MB file) uploaded from a frontend request. However, I do not think I can pass the data from the frontend request via TaskOptions.Builder as I will get the "Task size too large" error.

I need some kind of "temporary" data store for the uploaded data, that can be deleted once the task has successfully processed it.

**Option A**: Store uploaded data in memcache, pass the key to the task. This is likely going to work most of the time, except when the data is evicted BEFORE the task is processed. If this can be resolved, sounds like a great solution.

**Option B**: Store the data in datastore (an Entity created just for this purpose). Pass the id to the task. The task is responsible for deleting the entity when it is done.

**Option C**: Use the Blobstore service. This, IMHO, is similar in concept to Option B.

At the moment, i'm thinking option B is the most feasible way.

Appreciate any advise on the best way to handle these situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are storing data larger than 1mb, you must use the blobstore. (Yes, you can segment the data in the datastore, but it's not worth the work.) There are two things to look out for, however. Make sure that you write the data to the blobstore in chunks less than 1mb. Also, since the task queue is idempotent, your tasks should not fail if the requested blobstore key does not exist, since a previous task may have deleted it already.

Comment: When you say "Make sure that you write the data to the blobstore in chunks less than 1mb", you mean datastore instead of blobstore right? ...as blobstore file size limitations are much higher. Going with option C. :-)

Comment: I think i know what you mean now. You are referring to the "blobstore" reads - BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService().fetchData() size cannot be more than 1MB.

Comment: No, I am referring to writes to the blobstore. See: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore. On the f.write('data') call, you will have a large array. This array must be segmented into parts smaller than 1mb, then you call f.write() on each segment.

Answer (score 1):

Option B doesn't work too, because maximum entity size is 1mb too. Same limit as for task.

Option A can't give any guarantee, values can expire from the memcache at any time, and may be expired prior to the expiration deadline set for the value.

Imho, Option C is best for your needs

Comment: Thanks splix & @flipps0. You guys are great. All seem to point to option C, too bad I can only tick one right answer. Happy New Year!